# I want to call the entire alphabet multiple letters deep on a site, is that easy to do

Tags: linux, shell, wget

I want to call the entire alphabet multiple letters deep on an effort to pre cache a site before launch.

EX:

```
example.com/search?id=a

example.com/search?id=z

example.com/search?id=aa

example.com/search?id=zz

example.com/search?id=aaa

example.com/search?id=zzz
```

Is there an efficient way to **wget/etc** in that manner that from the command line/shell?

Comment: Are you trying to use the command line by itself or are you writing a program to do this? If you don't have access to for loops such as in a programming language, it would be very tedious.

Comment: Look at combining `wget` with `jot`.

Comment: Got it: Used php's file_get_contents() in conjunction with a loop that took advantage of php not being statically typed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With `curl`:

```
curl -# 'example.com/search?id=[a-z]' > /dev/null
curl -# 'example.com/search?id=[a-z][a-z]' > /dev/null
curl -# 'example.com/search?id=[a-z][a-z][a-z]' > /dev/null
```

With `wget` (and bash):

```
wget -O/dev/null 'example.com/search?id='{{a..z},{a..z}{a..z},{a..z}{a..z}{a..z}}
```

Not sure it's efficient, though, but it might get you going a little bit.